# How to insert visual compser post grid shortcode in a custom page template?

Tags: shortcode

After some research I've identified this method on inserting post grid shortocde into different page templates but it doesn't seem to work and this might be why, according to the visual composer plugin author:

> Currently it is not possible because Grid requires special hashkey which is stored in meta data of the each post. Each hashkey is unique and related to information in meta about grid attributes. The reason of such implementation is security. Because vc getting data grid from ajax request and data passed to this request is ID.

Is there a way to fix the code to make it work?

To investigate this is the page I am trying to implement the code in.

http://www.blogfort.com/articles/journals/

Please help, it's important.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[vc_row css=".vc_custom_1479903476287{margin-top: 0px !important;}"][vc_column][vc_basic_grid post_type="post" max_items="6" element_width="2" gap="0" item="2904" grid_id="vc_gid:1479927728768-be91949c-4e72-1" taxonomies="47" css=".vc_custom_1479903767331{margin-top: 0px !important;margin-right: 0px !important;margin-bottom: 0px !important;margin-left: 0px !important;padding-top: 0px !important;padding-right: 0px !important;padding-bottom: 0px !important;padding-left: 0px !important;}" el_class="featured"][/vc_column][/vc_row]'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that's what they says in their docs then I think the time you'd spend trying to get around it will be much more than simply doing the following:

Create a page.

Put the grid shortcode in (normally, in the page builder).

Then save the page and visit it (as in go to the page on the website front end).

View source and copy the html produced by the shortcode.

Paste it in to your template, keeping all CSS classes/ids.

This will produce the exact same visual features, as long as all required vc stylesheets and js is being included. If not, then enqueue the required assests manually for that particular template.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you man, you saved my ass. I'm just a simple user with some basic html knowledge so I wouldn't know much, tried some ways but nothing worked, wish I knew it was this simple. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: You're welcome, Gabriel. Feel free to upvote my answer if you're happy this answered your question (click the up arrow to the left of my answer) or mark the answer as accepted (click the tick beneath the down arrow) :)

Comment: Done. And upvoted but it says something minimum 15 reputation points, still recorded but not visible.

Comment: While you gave the fix I just noticed it vanishes in Chrome for some reason so I'm coming to you again for help. I've done exactly as you said, it works fine in Firefox, but in Chrome it appears to load and it vanishes without returning any results. Any ideas why? Check this [link](http://www.blogfort.com/articles/journals/) in both browsers if it's not too much to ask.

Comment: now guess what, it's not displaying in Firefox either, it was fine all day, now i checked it it appears to load for a second and then it vanishes having nothing loaded. I swear I'm gonna go insane.